# Is it theoretically possible to create Universe in the lab?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, universe

If the universe took birth without the help of consciousness then is it theoretically possible to [create a Universe in the lab](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990NuPhB.339..417F/abstract) ? If yes , how is this created Universe will be different from multiverse which gets created with every wave function collapse(according to multiverse theory interpretation of quantum mechanics)?

PS: I had asked this question in physics stack exchange site but it was closed because it wasn’t a mainstream physics question. I need some answers and I don’t know where else to ask. There are members of this site who have good experience in physics so I am giving it a try here.

Comment: In your mind, what would distinguish the creation of a Universe from the product of any other kind of action?

Comment: Multiverse does not get created by collapses. In MWI, where we have the multiverse, there are no collapses, it is part of the MWI's main selling points. Multiverse always and ever exists, it has multiple branches ("universes"), and not even they are created. They also always exist in a superposition, and time evolution simply takes our "experience" along one of them. A universe in a lab is not a pre-existent branch in a superposition like "universes" of MWI, it would actually have to be created.

Comment: @Conifold thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Why a lab? Why not in your bedroom, or at the theatre while failing to be engrossed by the latest fashionable production of Yawning, sorry, Waiting for Godot? I don't know, off-hand, how the Universe was caused, but if what some people say is true- that it was the result of a random quantum fluctuation- then perhaps it is just a matter of waiting for a sufficiently long time.

How would it be different from the new universes created every fraction of a pico second according the the MWI? Good question! Presumably, within the newly created Universe the laws of QM would continue to apply, so if the MWI were true then you would have an infinite number of branching Universes each of which would contain a copy of the new Universe which would itself start branching an infinite number of times, and... heavens, this is all proving too much- I think I will have a lie down.

Answer (score 1):

No, it couldn't be created in a lab because it would be too big to fit.